# How can you create a non binary tree with just the constructor?

Tags: java, tree

The constructor takes in two parameters which is the the Name of the Parent node and a list of its children nodes?
constructor:

```
public Node(String Parent, Array[] Children-nodes)
```

The constructing of the tree will be

```
 new Node("Parent",
new Node("Child1",
new Node("Child2",
new Node("Child of Child 2")
),
),
)
```

Comment: No can do sir, but I have a repo in github that has trees, lists and everything in between 

https://github.com/AntDraws13/EstructurasDinamicas

As per your question, it'll be deleted because you're asking how to do something instead of a specific topic.

Comment: The type of the children array must be `Node[]`. This is perfectly possible, contrary to what you have just been told. The trick is that you have to construct from the leaves up.